# Use selected item from DropDownList to fill in Textboxes in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor

This was automatically generated
[image: My view]
Now i want to get the owners name that paard(horse), but be able to edit the owners name after selecting the horse.
[image: This is the controller of that view]

I've tried searching everywhere, but i couldn't find anything similar to what i want. Hopefully you guys can help me out.

Comment: u cannot use dropdown list. You may use autocomplete instead.

Comment: Don't post the code image instead of the code itself !